# String.xml with name of button

Tags: android

need help with @string resources in android.

strings.xml

```
<string name ="jugar"></string>
```

aplication.xml

```
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/jugar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/jugar" />
```

result: Button jugar -> text is empty, no visible in aplication.

thanks!

Comment: <string name="jugar">Text you want</string>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put some text value in your string like such:

```
<string name ="jugar">Jugar</string>
```

the `name` attribute is only a reference, not the text value.